# Fetch images only from wordpress posts

Tags: image, wordpress, post, tags, categories

In wordpress, when a post category (or tag) is clicked, all posts that match the clicked category (or tag) is returned, because of `<?php the_content(); ?>`

In my case, every post has an image in it, so how can I only fetch the images when a category (or tag) is clicked? I'm not familiar what code I need to use.

Update: I'm trying not to use plugins. My apologies for not mentioning that earlier. What I'm trying to achieve is something like [The Sartorialist](http://thesartorialist.com) - All posts have images, click on any category (or tag) associated with any post and only images are fetched.

Update 2: I tried this:

```
 <?php   

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '</li>';
          }
     }

 ?>
```

The only weird thing is, and I'm trying to figure out, another image from the media library also shows up, without it being in any of my posts.

I also found [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-archives/) which is very close to what I want, but unfortunately it has to be in a separate page, not the in category page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with something like this:

```
<?php

function getImage($num) {
global $more;
$more = 1;
$link = get_permalink();
$content = get_the_content();
$count = substr_count($content, '<img');
$start = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
$imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
$post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
$imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
$postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd+1);
$postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '',$postOutput);;
$image[$i] = $postOutput;
$start=$imgEnd+1;
}
if(stristr($image[$num],'<img')) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$image[$num]."</a>"; }
$more = 0;
}

?>
```

*[source](http://bavotasan.com/2009/retrieve-the-first-image-from-a-wordpress-post/)*

Comment: I tried it, but nothing showed up when I clicked on a category. The page was totally blank. See Update 2 above.

Comment: This is to get for 1 post. you may need to alter it a bit for running whole category

Comment: Going through this with a bit of more focus. It worked out. At the same time I found out that it was the same as what @Mark pointed out to begin with. Thank you both.

Comment: @phptinkerer: You should have accepted my answer. Btw, i dug it for you myself. Atleast VOTE up for my Answer Please.

Comment: I appreciate that you dug it up, but I have to be fair to @Mark too. Voted.